# Nhibernate and log4net logs

Tags: nhibernate, log4net

I have a customer using an application called 'Nhibernate' and a plugin called Log4net. Both work in conjunction to generates a log file.

My problem is that once **nhibernate.log** reaches more than 200MB a new file is generated and the old file is renamed **NHibernate.log.1**

Is there way to avoid the segmentation of the log files and makes the log readable even after 200MB.

Thank you for your responses.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can open the NHibernate.log.1 with any text editor. If you open the configuration file you can change the logname pattern for the NHibernate logger file property.

If you want all in one file you can change the appender to a normal fileappender.

An link to an older blog with some information on how to do the configuration for the NHibernate appender: http://geekswithblogs.net/opiesblog/archive/2006/09/29/92721.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Log4net has a configurator that defines the max size of the file and the number of extra files created after reaching this max size.

If you want everything on a single file, you can re-defines these properties.

You probably have an .config file or on your app.config/web.config an set of xml properties that defines these parameters.

This is an example of the property you are looking for:

```
<maximumFileSize value="200MB" />
```